# pkg2ng throwing tons of errors about unknown keywords

Tags: freebsd, package-management

So... the `pkg_*` tools are deprecated, EOL scheduled for September 2014. Time to convert to pkgng. They have provided the `pkg2ng` tool provided for that. But when I run it, it throws tons of error messages. I don't know if I can ignore them or if that will introduce subtle errors.

```
# pkg2ng
Converting packages from /var/db/pkg
Converting libsigsegv-2.10...
pkg: fopen(/usr/ports/Keywords/display.yaml): No such file or directory
pkg: unknown keyword display, ignoring @display
Installing libsigsegv-2.10... done
Converting m4-1.4.17,1...
pkg: fopen(/usr/ports/Keywords/mtree.yaml): No such file or directory
pkg: unknown keyword mtree, ignoring @mtree
Installing m4-1.4.17,1... done
Converting libiconv-1.14_2...
pkg: fopen(/usr/ports/Keywords/mtree.yaml): No such file or directory
pkg: unknown keyword mtree, ignoring @mtree
Installing libiconv-1.14_2... done
Converting tdb-1.2.12,1...
pkg: fopen(/usr/ports/Keywords/conflicts.yaml): No such file or directory
pkg: unknown keyword conflicts, ignoring @conflicts
Installing tdb-1.2.12,1... done

(and so on)
```

Google doesn't give me much, only numerous repetitions of the thread that this post stems from: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-pkg/2013-June/000052.html
I find that pretty weird, it looks as if there were only 2 or 3 people on the planet having this problem, one of whom would be me.

So...

- Anyone had this problem, too?
- Can the error messages be ignored? (But why are they printed, then? Remember, this is the package database, which is pretty central to the system.)
- What can I do to rectify the situation.

Comment: Do you have a ports tree somewhere (the `/usr/ports` hierarchy) ?

Comment: Ports tree is in the standard location, but that's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FreeBSD manual regarding `pkgng`](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/pkgng-intro.html):

> The package database conversion may emit errors as the contents are converted to the new version. Generally, these errors can be safely ignored. However, a list of third-party software that was not successfully converted will be listed after pkg2ng has finished and these applications must be manually reinstalled.

These errors are related to `display`, `mtree`, `conflicts` keywords handling: nothing to worry about as these are either obsolete or exotic cases. As stated in the doc, the installed package which did failed to convert would be listed.

The bottom line here is that the new `pkg info` give you all the packages you had.

Comment: [Developers confirm](https://github.com/freebsd/pkg/issues/741).

Comment: The `pkg info` listing, however, is not useful. With several 100 packages, you don't want to go through the list manually.

Comment: Meanwhile they have apparently fixed this usability problem. When i ran `pkg2ng` recently, the error messages were no longer prduced.